# Select dentro de Select

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo uma página de produtos que lista dentro de cada categoria todos os produtos relacionados (são várias categorias e vários produtos). Como o código abaixo, ele 'roda' todas as categorias e o que eu preciso fazer, e **onde preciso de ajuda, é listar os produtos**.

```
    <?php do { ?> //Listagem das Categorias 
        <div class="row" id="<?php echo $row_ListaCategoria['descricao'];?>">
            <div class="header-content">

                <!--CATEGORIA-->
                <div class="separador"><!--Nome da Categoria-->
                    <h3><?php echo $row_ListaCategoria['descricao']; ?></h3>
                    <hr/>
                </div>

                <!--PRODUTOS--><!--Rodar todos os produtos da categoria $row_ListaCategoria['id']-->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3-edit thumb">
                    <div class="box clearfix">

                        <!--IMAGEM PRODUTO-->
                        <a href="img/produtos/id/101.1032.png" class="thumbnail text-center thumbnail-edit thumbnail_wrapper no-border-radius pop" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="CHICOTE PARA REPARO ALTERNADOR VW/CHICOTE P/REPARO SENSOR PRESS" data-footer="TC Chicotes">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-form-edit" src="img/produtos/id/101.1032.png" alt="#" />
                        </a>

                        <!--INFORMAÇÕES PRODUTO-->
                        <div class="product-text">
                            <h4>CHICOTE PARA REPARO ALTERNADOR VW/CHICOTE P/REPARO SENSOR PRESS</h4>
                            <p><strong>Código:</strong> 101.1152<br>
                            <strong>Aplicação:</strong> 400<br>
                            <strong>Obs:</strong> N/F</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>  

            </div>

        </div>
    <?php } while ($row_ListaCategoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($ListaCategoria)); ?>
```

Para buscar as categorias utilizo:

```
mysql_select_db($database_Conect, $Conect);
$query_ListaCategoria = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_categoria WHERE id_empresa = %s ORDER BY descricao", GetSQLValueString($colname_listaFabrica, "int"));
$ListaCategoria = mysql_query($query_ListaCategoria, $Conect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ListaCategoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($ListaCategoria);
$totalRows_ListaCategoria = mysql_num_rows($ListaCategoria);
```

Banco:

(Categoria)

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `data_cadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `id_empresa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

(Empresa)

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data_cadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ativo` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

(Produto)

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tbl_categoria_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tbl_empresa_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_categoria_id`)
    REFERENCES tbl_categoria(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`tbl_empresa_id`)
    REFERENCES tbl_empresa(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Um exemplo de como seria mostrado:

[image: Categoria "Chicotes", todos os produtos de chicotes listados abaixo e logo depois a próxima categoria]

Não consegui resolver este problema ainda, tentei desenvolver uma function para selecionar os produtos porém não deu certo ainda.
Estou aberto caso tenham alguma sugestão, ideia ou solução.

Agradeço desde já a todos!

Comment: Porque você não cria os selects de acordo com suas categorias? Ex.: select * from produto p where p.categoria='Pecas carros' - select * from produto p where p.categoria='Pecas motos'. ai na sua página você imprime a lista dentro de cada categoria referente ao select.

Comment: Porque é um sistema de uma representada, então tenho várias empresas com categorias diferentes. Aí fica inviável fazer um select para cada. Se eu não te entendido errado.

Comment: Os Produtos e as Categorias compartilham alguma chave (key) ?

Comment: Sim, tbl_produto possui ID de tbl_categoria e de tbl_empresa @FleuquerLima

Comment: Para vc selecionar a categoria você já tem que ter selecionado a empresa certo? O produto seria filtrado pela id_empresa e id_categoria. Sua duvida é em como montar esta Query?

Comment: @FleuquerLima, sim, é isso mesmo, eu já estou selecionando as categorias de acordo com a empresa, me mostra as categorias de forma perfeita, mas dentro de cada categoria eu preciso mostrar todos os produtos dessa. não sei se seria feito na mesma query. A Principio tentei fazer uma função que recebesse o valor da categoria e selecionasse os produtos, mas não deu certo. Se for possível realizar na mesma query seria ótimo.

Comment: Da pra fazer na mesma Query sim, só precisa saber o que passar de parametro.

Comment: @FleuquerLima, certo, eu atualizei com mais informações caso possa me ajudar com essa query

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer na mesma Query sim.

Você pode fazer a comparação diretamente adicionando as duas tabelas e dando-lhes apelidos com "AS", e quando for chamar os campos basta colocar o apelido na frente para referenciar de onde vem o campo.

Exemplo:

```
select C.campo_tabela_categoria, P.C.campo_tabela_produto 
from tbl_categoria AS C, tbl_produto AS P 
where id_empresa = %s AND C.id_categoria = P.id_categoria 
order by C.descricao
```

Ou podes usar (o que seria ate mais correto) INNER JOIN, por exemplo:

```
select C.campo_tabela_categoria, P.C.campo_tabela_produto 
from tbl_categoria AS C INNER JOIN tbl_produto AS P on C.id_categoria = P.id_categoria;
```

Se quiser saber mais sobre joins veja este post: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Espero que isto ajude;

Att;

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender esse raciocínio para o que eu descrevi. Tenho que selecionar _em cada categoria de tal empresa todos os produtos_. Utilizando JOIN eu não conseguiria mostrar somente uma vez Categoria e abaixo todos os produtos, e logo depois outra categoria com todos os produtos novamente..